# How to achieve persistence for each unique user instead of localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, firebase, persistence

I have a recipe builder CRUD type app. The main window displays users current recipe, user can click add ingredient button and edit his recipe whichever way he likes.

With localStorage I achieve persistence on page refresh and everything works perfectly.

**ingredient  selection component:**

```
// This code below is for choosing a single ingredient. useEffect runs when I add, remove or update ingredient.

  useEffect(() => {
    // more code here
    localStorage.setItem("recipe", JSON.stringify(selectedRecipe));
    history.push("/recipewindow");
  }, [history, selectedRecipe]);
```

**main recipe display component:**

```
//This code below is for my main window, where the full recipe is displayed. useEffect runs when
component is mounted

  useEffect(() => {
    const stateData = localStorage.getItem("recipe");
    stateData && setSelectedRecipe(JSON.parse(stateData));
    console.log(JSON.parse(stateData));
  }, [setSelectedRecipe]);
```

However, after implementing user authentication in my app, I just realised that localStorage stores the same data regardless of the user, so if I have 3 different accounts they will all have the same recipe window.

How can I achieve the persistence for each unique user?

Do I put the data into Firestore database like this: **Users collection/ user1234 / current_recipe** and keep storing and listening to changes from front end or is that going to be too slow?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using local storage for this. Local storage is inefficient.

All data should be stored on a database somewhere and downloaded as needed.

If you want to preserve state across components a good option would be to use something like redux (you could also use context, but redux has more features, prevents a lot of potential bugs and can also be used outside of react), but every time your user reloads their page, the content for that page should be downloaded from an external api.